# clientConnector bean with JBoss 7.2.0

Tags: java, spring, jboss, rmi, jmx

I am currently trying to perform the migration of a web application from **JOnAS 5.2.2** to **JBoss 7.2.0**.

I have a `clientConnector` bean with **JOnAS** which is configured like this :

```
  <bean id="clientConnector"
    class="com.zkz.myapp.common.jonas.JonasMBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean">
    <property name="jrmpUrl" value="$kpi{rmi.host}" />
  </bean>
```

What I did looks like something like that (I tried a lots of different things) :

```
  <bean id="clientConnector"
    class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmx-rmi" />
  </bean>
```

But I am getting this error :

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: rmi://localhost:1099/jmx-rmi -- service jboss.naming.context.j
ava.rmi:.localhost:1099.jmx-rmi
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:338) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:248) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean.connect(MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean.java:131) [spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.
2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean.java:119) [spring-context-3.1.2.RELEA
SE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514) [spring-beans
-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) [spring-beans-3.
1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: rmi://localhost:1099/jmx-rmi -- service jboss.naming.context.java.rmi:.localhost:1099.jmx-rmi
        at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:103)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:197)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:120)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:183)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:179)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1856) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:255) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        ... 49 more
```

I know there is something that I didn't get and there is not that much tutorial on internet.

Then, if someone could help me with an explaination, an example or even just a clue, it would be very appreciated.

Thank you